# How to get number of children like a variable in sass

Tags: html, css, sass, frontend

I need to know number if children in element for next construction:

```
$numberOfChildren = /*get from <div>*/
@if($numberOfChildren == 0){
    /* todo */
} @else { 
   /* todo */
}
```

Also can you please help me to check if an element is empty and return a boolean, it would solve my problem too.

Comment: This is not possible with sass. You can try using the nth child. Here is a link explaining it https://alistapart.com/article/quantity-queries-for-css

Answer (score 0):

For this case, the sass syntax is not made. You can try if you really need to count the div elements with javascript, on the other hand i recommend you the nth child like this:

```
p:nth-child(2) {
  background: red;
}
```

This would make the second `<p>` red.

or for more a more detailed example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/5FD3P/